How to extend HTTP requestContext using Playground or GraphiQL?
I am working on a GraphQL endpoint (actually it is Spring) and our consumers are frontend and mobile app developers. Our goal is to provide Playground* and/or GraphiQL with nicely prepared examples, so they don't have to spend their time dealing with GQL "specifics".
The problem I face now is that we travel data in the HTTP --raw-data and it is basically a json object. We usually inject/modify this by using GRO Bro/GGRO Injector plugins. But, what I am trying to figure out is that if we can skip these terrible tools and giving predefined values to our customers. I tried passing this data via headers (header tab), but it wasn't successful.
curl --data-raw is not a header.
So, the question is how can I send this raw data using Playground and/or GraphiQL? Is there a blog post about it?

I am aware of that Playground is not supported anymore

